# SQLite WHERE filter by date formatted as follows: "Wed Aug 03 08:00:00 PDT 2022"?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, datetime, where-clause

I have data in a SQLite table, with the datatype DATE. The data is formatted like the following, as an example:

"Wed Aug 03 08:00:00 PDT 2022"

If I wish to use a WHERE statement to filter by date, how do I do this with this date formatting?

Even better, what is the best way to either mask or modify this data to search using a more typical YYYY-MM-DD format?

If there's a similar question posted that answers this please let me know rather than being rude, I must have just missed it. I wouldn't ask without looking first :)

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html Show your schema, sample data, what you have tried, what you are trying to get. In general, read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/ and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't store dates in that format.
Actually, sqlite doesn't have an internal storage type for dates:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
>
> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

If you see data formatted as "Wed Aug 03 08:00:00 PDT 2022", it is probably a case of [Flexible Typing](https://www.sqlite.org/flextypegood.html) where sqlite stored a string value in a DATE field "as is" because it didn't manage to recognize it as a date.

So you need to convert it to a proper date value (be it a number or a string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format) by extracting the values from the string with string manipulation functions. Also note that sqlite desn't have time zones recognition (besides of localtime).